# html table white-space: nowrap not working?

Tags: html, css

I have a KnockoutJS template that creates a input[type=text] and a select next to each other with no `<br/>` inbetween. However it puts a linebreak between even with `white-space: nowrap;` I'm currently testing in chrome.

**CSS:**

```
table.grid tbody tr td {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**Question**: Why isn't `white-space: nowrap;` not working? Is there a fix to this or a way around it?

Comment: Are you sure the `input` and `select` dont have `display:block` set?

Comment: Is that the problem? :( hmmm...okay I didn't know that would conflict. Thanks. What would be an appropriate display replacement that wouldn't conflict?

Comment: `display:inline` or `inline-block` should do...I'll post it as an answer for future reference

Comment: If I do that it causes the selects to push into the adjacent table cell. Table & Block seems to be the only one that doesn't do that but they don't agree with `white-space: nowrap;`.

Comment: if you set `overflow:hidden` on the element with `nowrap` they wont 'appear' in the adjacent cell. However, if the cell is too small for them to appear inline, and you want them both to be displayed, either remove the `nowrap`, increase the cell width or make them block level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted above, this may be due to either/both your `input` and/or `select` elements being set to display at block level using `display:block` which will force them onto a 'new line' instead of displaying `inline` and following through with the anticipate `nowrap` behaviour

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/Y2mP8/4/)

Comment: Alrighty, thanks for the information. I figured out there was a `width: 100%` style on one of my selects causing the table to go berserk. Everything auto-fit after I fixed that, which is what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a `div` inside my `td`. Inside the `div` had 2 `button`. Even with `white-space:nowrap`, `display:inline-block` and `position:relative` applied to all these elements it did still wrapped.

**For me what did the trick was removing a `float:left`** that was being applied to the buttons, from another class, since it "kind of force" the browser to act as those elements were `display:block`.